# Incorrectly displaying data using JTable+focusLost()

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpopupmenu, focuslistener

I want to display correctly in the textbox data when selecting any rows from multiple tables.

- When I right-click on any row of Table 1 I get `table1: 1`. If I click on any row of Table 2 I also get `table1: 1` (but it should be `table2: 1`. ) .
- When I left-click on the table 1 or 2 and then right-click I do not get any result.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class FocusTable extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField; //Show selected row data here
    private JTable table1;
    private JTable table2;
    private JTable table3;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FocusTable frame = new FocusTable();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public FocusTable() {
        setTitle("Test Focus Lost Table");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        textField = new JTextField();
        contentPane.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        contentPane.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //----------------Create JPopupMenu-----------------
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem menuItemOpen = new JMenuItem("Show!");
        popupMenu.add(menuItemOpen);
        //---------------------------------------------------

        table1 = new JTable();
        table1.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
            //Show menu by pressing the right button
        table1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton( e )) {
                    Point point = e.getPoint();
                    int column = table1.columnAtPoint(point);
                    int row = table1.rowAtPoint(point);
                    table1.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);
                }
            }
        });
            //Clear selected row
        table1.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                //textField.setText("Focus Lost table 1");
                table1.clearSelection();
            }
        });
            //Default model of Table 1
        table1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {"table1: 1", null, null, null, null},
                {"table1: 2", null, null, null, null},
                {"table1: 3", null, null, null, null},
                {"table1: 4", null, null, null, null},
                {"table1: 5", null, null, null, null},
                {"table1: 6", null, null, null, null},
                {"table1: 7", null, null, null, null},
                {"table1: 8", null, null, null, null},
                {"table1: 9", null, null, null, null},
            },
            new String[] {
                "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column"
            }
        )
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
           //all cells false
           return false;
        }   
    });
        tabbedPane.addTab("TabTable1", null, table1, null);

        table2 = new JTable();
        table2.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
            //Show menu by pressing the right button
        table2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton( e )) {
                    Point point = e.getPoint();
                    int column = table2.columnAtPoint(point);
                    int row = table2.rowAtPoint(point);
                    table2.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);
                }
            }
        });
            //Clear selected row
        table2.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                //textField.setText("Focus Lost table 2");
                table2.clearSelection();
            }
        });
            //Default model of Table 2
        table2.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {null, "table2: 1", null, null, null},
                {null, "table2: 2", null, null, null},
                {null, "table2: 3", null, null, null},
                {null, "table2: 4", null, null, null},
                {null, "table2: 5", null, null, null},
                {null, "table2: 6", null, null, null},
                {null, "table2: 7", null, null, null},
                {null, "table2: 8", null, null, null},
                {null, "table2: 9", null, null, null},
            },
            new String[] {
                "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column"
            }
        ){
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
           //all cells false
           return false;
        }   
    });
        tabbedPane.addTab("TabTable2", null, table2, null);

        table3 = new JTable(); 
            //Clear selected row when focus lost        
        table3.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                table2.clearSelection();
            }
        });
            //Show menu by pressing the right button
        table3.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton( e )) {
                    Point point = e.getPoint();
                    int column = table3.columnAtPoint(point);
                    int row = table3.rowAtPoint(point);
                    table3.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);
                }
            }
        });
        //Default model of Table 3
        table3.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {null, null, "table 3: 1", null, null},
                {null, null, "table 3: 2", null, null},
                {null, null, "table 3: 3", null, null},
                {null, null, "table 3: 4", null, null},
                {null, null, "table 3: 5", null, null},
                {null, null, "table 3: 6", null, null},
                {null, null, "table 3: 7", null, null},
                {null, null, "table 3: 8", null, null},
                {null, null, "table 3: 9", null, null},
            },
            new String[] {
                "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column"
            }
        ){
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
           //all cells false
           return false;
        }   
    });
        table3.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);

        tabbedPane.addTab("TabTable3", null, table3, null);

        //---------------------------Checking the selected table-------------------------------
        menuItemOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(table1.getSelectedRow()!=-1){
                    textField.setText(table1.getValueAt(table1.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                }else if(table2.getSelectedRow()!=-1){
                    textField.setText(table2.getValueAt(table2.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
                }else if(table3.getSelectedRow()!=-1){
                    textField.setText(table3.getValueAt(table3.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey there. Try and ask your question *before* dumping your code. Also, You should definitely narrow what code is here. Find out which specific function (or lines) are the source of the problem. I also removed noise from your question, such as `help me`. We know you need help, that's why you ask. You should definitely clarify your question. What textbox data? I will not read your hundreds of lines to understand what it is. We **dramatically** lack context.

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier: hi Felix! Thanks for the tip ! I thought it would be good to show a workable code .

Comment: Hey Tomas! Yes, you are right that showing *some* code is a good idea. But honestly, read your question and try to imagine being me. I don't know anything about your project. How am I supposed to understand anything about your question without **analyzing your code** for who knows how long before being able to figure what is going on? If you want to have your question answered, be sure it *is* answerable, and right now, except by being you and/or spending considerable amount of time, it's kinda hard...

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier: ok, I understand you. I really sat a long time over this code and decided to write here.

Comment: looks like someone with relevant experience did take the time to answer you :) don't get me wrong: I look forward for you to continue using this site.

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier: Thanks, you are very good man :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't play around with the FocusListener. There is no need to clear the table selection. Users don't like to have the row selection disappear as they move from tab to tab. So get rid of the FocusListener and leave the row selection as is.

Instead you can get the currently focused table by doing something like:

```
menuItemOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        JMenuItem mi = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
        JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu)mi.getParent();
        JTable table = (JTable)popup.getInvoker();

        if (table.equals(table1))
        {
            textField.setText(table1.getValueAt(table1.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
        }
        else if (table.equals(table2))
        {
            textField.setText(table2.getValueAt(table2.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
        }
        else if (table.equals(table3))
        {
            textField.setText(table3.getValueAt(table3.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString());
        }
    }
});
```